# How to find 'active' snapshots that cause sonarqube upgrade to 5.0 to fail?

Tags: database, oracle, sonarqube, upgrade, sonarqube-5.0

I’m getting the same error as Julien Lancelot answered re:

[Failed to upgrade SonarQube from 4.5 to 5.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339230/failed-to-upgrade-sonarqube-from-4-5-2-to-5-0)

ie

```
2015.02.18 14:56:26 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  PopulateProjectsUuidColumns: migrating ====================================
2015.02.18 14:56:43 ERROR web[o.s.s.d.m.DatabaseMigrator]  Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.server.db.migrations.v50.PopulateProjectsUuidColum
nsMigration
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
### Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:26) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.select(DefaultSqlSession.java:130) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.select(DefaultSqlSession.java:122) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
        at org.sonar.core.persistence.DbSession.select(DbSession.java:125) ~[sonar-core-5.0.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.v50.PopulateProjectsUuidColumnsMigration.execute(PopulateProjectsUuidColumnsMigration.java:65) ~[sonar-server-5.0.jar:na]
```

Julian mentioned

> With the help of the SQL query and the modified jar to add some debug,
>   I've finally found from where the issue is coming : your project with
>   id 39554 **have 2 active snapshots** (1234385 and 1234386). **This use case
>   is not managed as this should never happen**.

How can I identify the mentioned ‘active’ snapshots and delete them so this step succeeds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to upgrade SonarQube from 4.5.2 to 5.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339230/failed-to-upgrade-sonarqube-from-4-5-2-to-5-0)

Comment: The referenced question does not explain how to identify the offending data - these steps where done in offline chats emails. Hence this new question.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Julian via email, here is the sql

> SELECT snapshots.id, COUNT(*) FROM projects INNER JOIN snapshots ON
>   snapshots.project_id=projects.id AND snapshots.islast=true GROUP BY
>       snapshots.id HAVING 
>       COUNT(*) > 1