# Database Migration fails from Sonar 4.5.1 to Sonar 5.0.1 with NullPointerException

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I've run into a problem with my upgrade from Sonar 4.5.1 to 5.0.1. The database migration step fails with "Error querying database." "Cause: Java.lang.NullPointerException."

Would anyone know how to proceed with finding the cause of the problem? I've tried the query for projects without scope in the [Failed to upgrade SonarQube from 4.5.2 to 5.0 post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339230/failed-to-upgrade-sonarqube-from-4-5-2-to-5-0). My error is very similar to the error in this post. 
I've also tried the active snapshots script from  [How to find 'active' snapshots that cause sonarqube upgrade 5.0 to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588095/how-to-find-active-snapshots-that-cause-sonarqube-upgrade-to-5-0-to-fail) but nothing is returned. Does anyone know what else I can try in order to find the problem?

System Info:

- OS: Linux / amd64 / 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
- Sonar version: 4.5.1
- Java Version 1.7.0_51-b13
- Database Oracle Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition
- Database Driver Oracle JDBC driver 11.2.0.3

Error log:

```
2015.03.10 17:06:36 INFO  RubyThread-9: /opt/sonar/sonar-5.0.1/web/WEB-INF/app/models/database_migration_manager.rb:102 web[sql]  2ms Executed SQL: SELECT version FROM schema_migrations
2015.03.10 17:06:36 INFO  RubyThread-9: /opt/sonar/sonar-5.0.1/web/WEB-INF/app/models/database_migration_manager.rb:102 web[DbMigration]  ==  PopulateProjectsUuidColumns: migrating ====================================
2015.03.10 17:06:37 INFO  RubyThread-9: /opt/sonar/sonar-5.0.1/web/WEB-INF/app/models/database_migration_manager.rb:102 web[sql]  358ms Executed SQL: SELECT p.id AS "id", p.uuid AS "uuid", p.project_uuid AS "projectUuid", s.root_project_id AS "projectId", s.id AS "snapshotId", s.path AS "snapshotPath", p.scope AS "scope" FROM projects p LEFT OUTER JOIN snapshots s ON s.project_id = p.id AND s.islast = 1 WHERE p.scope = 'PRJ' AND p.root_id IS NULL
2015.03.10 17:06:37 INFO  RubyThread-9: /opt/sonar/sonar-5.0.1/web/WEB-INF/app/models/database_migration_manager.rb:102 web[sql]  9ms Executed SQL: SELECT p.id AS "id", p.uuid AS "uuid", p.project_uuid AS "projectUuid", p.module_uuid AS "moduleUuid", p.module_uuid_path AS "moduleUuidPath", s.root_project_id AS "projectId", s.id AS "snapshotId", s.path AS "snapshotPath", p.scope AS "scope" FROM projects root INNER JOIN snapshots root_snapshot ON root_snapshot.project_id = root.id AND root_snapshot.islast = 1 INNER JOIN snapshots s ON s.root_snapshot_id = root_snapshot.id AND s.islast = 1 INNER JOIN projects p ON p.id = s.project_id WHERE root.id = ? - parameters are: <12700>
2015.03.10 17:06:38 INFO  RubyThread-9: /opt/sonar/sonar-5.0.1/web/WEB-INF/app/models/database_migration_manager.rb:102 web[sql]  5ms Executed SQL: SELECT p.id AS "id", p.uuid AS "uuid" FROM projects p INNER JOIN projects root ON root.id = p.root_id WHERE root.id = ? AND p.uuid IS NULL AND p.enabled=0 - parameters are: <12700>
2015.03.10 17:06:38 INFO  RubyThread-9: /opt/sonar/sonar-5.0.1/web/WEB-INF/app/models/database_migration_manager.rb:102 web[sql]  3ms Executed SQL: SELECT p.id AS "id", p.uuid AS "uuid" FROM projects p INNER JOIN projects root_one ON root_one.id = p.root_id INNER JOIN projects root_two ON root_two.id = root_one.root_id WHERE root_two.id=? AND p.uuid IS NULL AND p.enabled=0 - parameters are: <12700>
2015.03.10 17:06:38 INFO  RubyThread-9: /opt/sonar/sonar-5.0.1/web/WEB-INF/app/models/database_migration_manager.rb:102 web[sql]  2ms Executed SQL: SELECT p.id AS "id", p.uuid AS "uuid", p.project_uuid AS "projectUuid", p.module_uuid AS "moduleUuid", p.module_uuid_path AS "moduleUuidPath", s.root_project_id AS "projectId", s.id AS "snapshotId", s.path AS "snapshotPath", p.scope AS "scope" FROM projects root INNER JOIN snapshots root_snapshot ON root_snapshot.project_id = root.id AND root_snapshot.islast = 1 INNER JOIN snapshots s ON s.root_snapshot_id = root_snapshot.id AND s.islast = 1 INNER JOIN projects p ON p.id = s.project_id WHERE root.id = ? - parameters are: <12677>
2015.03.10 17:06:38 ERROR RubyThread-9: /opt/sonar/sonar-5.0.1/web/WEB-INF/app/models/database_migration_manager.rb:102 web[o.s.s.d.m.DatabaseMigrator]  Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.server.db.migrations.v50.PopulateProjectsUuidColumnsMigration
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
### Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:26) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.select(DefaultSqlSession.java:130) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.select(DefaultSqlSession.java:122) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DbSession.select(DbSession.java:125) ~[sonar-core-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.v50.PopulateProjectsUuidColumnsMigration.execute(PopulateProjectsUuidColumnsMigration.java:65) ~[sonar-server-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.DatabaseMigrator.executeMigration(DatabaseMigrator.java:94) ~[sonar-server-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:455) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:316) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:61) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:198) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
```

Comment: Hi, could you send us the result of : SELECT p.id AS "id", p.uuid AS "uuid", p.project_uuid AS "projectUuid", p.module_uuid AS "moduleUuid", p.module_uuid_path AS "moduleUuidPath", s.root_project_id AS "projectId", s.id AS "snapshotId", s.path AS "snapshotPath", p.scope AS "scope" FROM projects root INNER JOIN snapshots root_snapshot ON root_snapshot.project_id = root.id AND root_snapshot.islast = 1 INNER JOIN snapshots s ON s.root_snapshot_id = root_snapshot.id AND s.islast = 1 INNER JOIN projects p ON p.id = s.project_id WHERE root.id = 12677 ?

Comment: Thanks Julien! That query didn't return any rows.

Comment: Ok, then could you give me the result of : select * form projects where id = 12677 ?

Comment: Id: 12677          Name: Stack Cxf       Enabled: 1         Scope: PRJ
Qualifier: BRC  KEE: org.lds.stack.ws:stack-cxf       Language: Java 
long_Name: Stack Cxf

Comment: I've created a new jar of sonar-server.jar in order to understand what is failing. Please remove your lib/server/sonar-server-5.0.1.jar and replace it by https://www.dropbox.com/s/dj3qzarylnql3cj/sonar-server-5.0.1.jar?dl=0. Then restart the migration, and send me the error message

Comment: > Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.server.db.migrations.v50.PopulateProjectsUuidColumnsMigration.
    
    2015.03.24 14:49:12 INFO  web[DbMigration] PopulateProjectsUuidColumns: migrating 
    2015.03.24 14:49:28 ERROR web[o.s.s.d.m.DatabaseMigrator]  Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.server.db.migrations.v50.PopulateProjectsUuidColumnsMigration
    org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
    ### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    ### Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Comment: Could you please send me the whole trace please ? What I need it just after the IllegalStateException

Comment: I am Sorry, here is a link to the full trace. http://pastebin.com/p87h5yRZ

Comment: Hi, from what I see in the log, the first query I've asked you to execute shouldn't have nothing. 
Could you restore a backup, restart the migration, and send me server logs after line "PopulateProjectsUuidColumns: migrating" ?
Could you also send me the result of the last query that will be executed, just before the exception ?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your help on this. I didn't run the first query myself, but I had asked a DBA to run it. I have now run it myself and it returned an error. ORA-00904: "P"."MODULE_UUID_PATH": invalid identifier. Is that query correct? The projects table doesn't have a module_uuid_path column. I've restored the DB and re-run the upgrade. The log is here. http://pastebin.com/BKC29GVW. I wasn't sure what you meant about the results of the last query before the exception. I included the the "CreateAnalysisReports:migrating" and "AddProjectNmaeToAnalysisReports:migrating" Just in case.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify to set the following property into sonar.properties : sonar.log.profilingLevel=FULL. It will allow me to see what is the last executed SQL. This SQL will contains the corrupted data. 
So please try again with this property.

Comment: Ok, that is what I was missing. Here is the link to the log after the new attempt. http://pastebin.com/AVV0djL4 . I ran the query just before the exception and it didn't return anything.

Comment: It's very strange that the query is returning nothing. 
I've created another jar of sonar-server.jar. Please remove your lib/server/sonar-server-5.0.1.jar, replace it by https://www.dropbox.com/s/dj3qzarylnql3cj/sonar-server-5.0.1.jar?dl=0, restore your backup, restart the migration and send me server logs after line "PopulateProjectsUuidColumns: migrating".

Comment: Here is the new log. http://pastebin.com/QrXJm9BU

Comment: Now I have more info ! It seems that one of your project was before a module, and was not correctly updated. Could you send me the result of : "SELECT * FROM PROJECTS WHERE id=12677" and "SELECT * FROM SNAPSHOTS WHERE ID = 44429" AND "SELECT * FROM SNAPSHOTS WHERE ID = 44808", in a CSV file or a format easy to read ?

Comment: Here is a csv file from the first query. https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ur2j59plct2s88/Projects.csv?dl=0 And here is the file from the second. https://www.dropbox.com/s/uc1maff60w79zy1/Snapshots.csv?dl=0 The third didn't return anything.

Comment: Your problem is the following one : the project 'org.lds.stack.ws:stack-cxf
' is not a project but a module. But as its column projects.root_id is null, it's considered as a project. Could you please send me the result of "SELECT * FROM PROJECTS WHERE id=12072". The result of this query should return the project of this module. If it's the case I think the best solution will be to set the project.root_id of the module to 12072. I will confirm you that with the result of the query.

Comment: Thanks Julien. Unfortunately, the query didn't return anything.

Comment: Looking at that module, it doesn't appear to have been scanned. I would love to just delete it if possible. Would you give any direction on how to do so?

Comment: Indeed, this module has to be removed. You should be able to remove it before the migration using one of : Settings -> Bulk Deletion -> Projects, then search the project by its name. If you couldn't find it, then look at Settings -> Bulk Deletion -> Ghosts tab, and see if the project is here.
If you could not delete it using the previous pages, you can try by using "DELETE FROM projects WHERE id=12677"

Comment: Did you manage to fix your issue ?

Comment: I'm trying the ghost delete. I'll let you know if it helps.

Comment: Deleting the ghost projects didn't help. I ended up deleting id=12677 and re-ran the upgrade. It failed with another component id =12681. This also has a link to the non-existent project 12072. Is there a way to find all components linked to 12072?

Comment: You can have the list of projects that are linked to 12072 by executing : SELECT * FROM projects INNER JOIN snapshots WHERE root_project_id = 12072.

Comment: That query throws an error. In the position of the Where clause, it expects Full, Inner, Join, Left, On, Right, or Using. Would this work instead? 
SELECT * FROM projects p 
INNER JOIN snapshots s 
ON p.id=s.project_id 
and s.root_project_id = 12072
This query returns a number of projects with a blank Root ID field. Would any project with a blank Root_ID field be a problem?

Comment: Oups, sorry indeed the join condition was missing in the query, the change you've made is correct. And indeed, projects with empty_id id having qualifiers different than 'TRK', 'VW', 'DEV' and 'LIB' are a problem. If this is the case, have a look at them and if you do not know them you can delete them.

Comment: That query returned over 540 projects. There are about 25 projects without a root_ID. All of them have a qualifier of BRC. Do you think all of them would be a problem? Also is there any further step to clean up data after a row is deleted from the project table?

Comment: You could delete the ones without root_id, as it's not normal. The clean up of snapshots and measures will be made by the "Database Cleaner".

Comment: I've gone in and removed all projects with an empty root_id and the qualifier BRC. Re-ran the migration and it failed again with the error querying database nullpointerexception. This time the object does have something in the root_id field. The log is here. http://pastebin.com/fWtBqhAE

Comment: Could you please send me the result of "SELECT * FROM projects where id IN (202262, 41102)" and "SELECT * FROM snapshots WHERE id IN (18104331, 18104330)" ? Thanks

Comment: Query results here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/23dohcr0p6v5pdm/Projects1.csv?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ht2nnux93y57k78/Snapshots1.csv?dl=0

Comment: Very strange, everything is normal for the component which is failing...

Comment: I've created a ticket to fix this issue : https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-6493

Comment: Thanks, I've started fresh from a blank database to get around this one. We're keeping the old db up for historical access.